# Linq Query Involving Association Tables

Tags: c#, linq, associations

```
IQueryable<Appeal> appeal = Repository.Appeals.Include("Case").Include("Case.Patient").Include("ShipmentAppeals").Where(ap => ap.CaseId == caseID);

IQueryable<ICollection<ShipmentAppeals>> shipmentAppeals = appeal.Select(ap => ap.ShipmentAppeals)
```

ShipmentAppeals is an association table between Appeal & Shipment entities.

I want to fetch those shipments from Repository.Shipments whose ShipmentID exists in above shipmentAppeals collection.

The query which I have written is as below. It does work but I want to avoid the for each loops:

```
 foreach (ICollection<ShipmentAppeals> sAppealOuter in shipmentAppeals.ToList())
        {
            foreach (ShipmentAppeals sAppealInner in sAppealOuter)
            {
                Shipment shipment = Repository.Shipments.First(s => s.ID == sAppealInner.ShipmentID);
                    caseShipments.Add(shipment);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: And what problem are you having writing such a query?

Comment: I have written the query but I have used 2 for each loops in it which I want to avoid.

Comment: Then show us what you tried, and explain the problem(s) with it, in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, we can use `SelectMany` to turn a sequence of collections of appeals into appeals.

Next, rather than going through each one of them and making a database query to go get a shipment we can instead use just a single query to get all of the shipments for all of the appeals.  This can be done through a `Join`.  (Or, in the event there are duplicate shipments that you don't want, you could use a `GroupJoin` and select the first item in each group.)

```
var caseShipments = shipmentAppeals.SelectMany(repository => repository)
    .Join(Repository.Shipments, appeal => appeal.ShipmentID
        , shipment => shipment.ID, (appeal, shipment) => shipment);
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var caseShipments = from repository in shipmentAppeals
                    from appeal in repository
                    join shipment in Repository.Shipments
                    on appeal.ShipmentID equals shipment.ID
                    select shipment;
```

Note that because of deferred execution this *entire query* will only make one DB round trip, since each query is used to compose another query, rather than being executed first.

Comment: Thank you. I did not knew the purpose of SelectMany. How can I use .include with the shipment entity that I am returning from the join ?

Comment: @user2585299 Call it on `Repository.Shipments` before passing it to `Join`.  You may wish to extract it out to a separate variable first, if you're doing much to it.